# Where does the Blendability come from?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, blend

In the last days I studied MVVM and I downloaded a couple of samples.

The following article is very good and it included the source code:
Better User and Developer Experiences – From Windows Forms to WPF with MVVM
http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/

When I first opened the project in Visual Studio 2013 all the fields and lists were empty like expected. The program is a RSS reader and I loaded one feed with lots of feed items which filled in all the fields in the form. But now even when I stopped the program I can see all the data in the design.

[image: All fields and lists are filled in in design mode]

This is obviously very good because it makes it a lot easier to see and possibly amend the design.
I think what I saw is covered under the name Blendability – but I am not sure about this.

Now my question: Where does this Blendability come from? I looked at the source code of the project and I don’t find where the data comes from in design mode.

Over the last days I installed a couple of extensions in Visual Studio and maybe I installed something which causes this behaviour. Or maybe this is some special function in this example (which is not mentioned anywhere in the article).

If possible please let me know where this Blendability comes from and how I can implement it in my own projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design time has a nifty feature where if you were to set the `DataContext` to a class, then that class will actually be **instantiated** at design-time.

It's quite probable that the `DataContext` of this particular window is a class with a constructor that executes the RSS reading code.

Take this for example:

```
public class MyRssReaderViewModel
{
    public MyRssReaderViewModel()
    {
        //Read RSS and populate properties
        LoadRSS();
    }

    public void LoadRSS()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now if you were to set the `DataContext` like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MyRssReaderViewModel/>
</Window.DataContex>
```

The designer will **instantiate** the class at design-time, and by extension call the `LoadRSS` method. Any elements that reference properties in your view model will update to display the bound data.

One important thing to note is that the class will be instantiated every time you **build** the project.

Comment: You are right, I checked and that is what happened. Thanks. An interesting detail is the following: I added a couple of debug.print in the code which has to be executed to show the RSS feed. And these debug.print messages don’t show when I open the form in design mode. They only show if I start the project and the form is opened.

Comment: I'm fairly certain `Debug.Print` only appears in the **Output Window**. Whether it appears there at design-time is unknown to me, however I would expect not. But anyway, check the output window.

Comment: I am aware that the debug.print messages should show in the Output Window. And they show there when I run the project but they don’t show if I open the window in design mode. For testing I added a message box behind the debug.print message in the View Model Constructor. And that message box also pops up when I open the form in design mode. This is just for information to illustrate that in fact the code is executed even in design mode – which I didn’t expect but now I understand why this happens.